# htpasswd in subdirectory not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

I wanted to **secure a subdirectory** of my website with the **htpasswd** user authentication.

But somehow the .htaccess in the root is overriding the .htaccess in the directory? How is this even possible?

**.htaccess in subdirectory**

```
AuthName "Foobar"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/foo.com/web/secretdirectory
require valid-user
```

The .htaccess in the root contains a lot of mod_rewrite but that does not influence the inheritance of the .htaccess files? Right?

**.htaccess root**

```
Satisfy Any
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} oxseo\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mod_rewrite_module_is=off
RewriteRule oxseo\.php$ oxseo.php?mod_rewrite_module_is=on [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/admin\/|\/core\/|\/export\/|\/modules\/|\/out\/|\/setup\/|\/tmp\/|\/views\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !(\.html|\/|\.jpg|\.css|\.pdf|\.doc|\.gif|\.png|\.js|\.htc)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/admin\/|\/core\/|\/export\/|\/modules\/|\/out\/|\/setup\/|\/tmp\/|\/views\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (\.html|\/)$ oxseo.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/out\/pictures\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg.php
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Thank you for any clues!

Comment: What's in your root .htaccess file and how do you now it's overriding it?

Comment: Does it even matter what is in the root .htaccess? I thought .htaccess cascades upwards, i.e. it will look in the current folder, then go up a level and so on?

Comment: Why do you have `Satisfy Any` at the top of your .htaccess? Try and remove that.

Comment: Yes thank you. I removed the "Satisfy Any". Now I can not access the secretdirectory anymore. The index.php in the root is redirecting to a custom error page and says that there is no such directory.